# Regexp RewriteCond doesn't match

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have these lines in a `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)(/.*|)$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %1%3.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)(/.*?)/?$ $1$3.php?lang=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

The third (commented) line doesn't work. Everything else is fine though. Can anyone point me out to what is wrong here ? The RewriteRule works very well, ie the file `$1$3.php` exists and is correctly displayed.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am rewriting `domain.xyz/Language/SubDir/page` to `domain.xyz/SubDir/page.php?lang=Language`

Comment: And what is `RewriteCond %1%3.php -f` used for? Do you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is just a qualified guess*

The regular expression values does not exist on the third line - You can not use values catched in a `RewriteCond` (e.g. `$1$3`, or as written in your example: `%1%3`) in another `RewriteCond`. You can only use the values (`$n`) in the `RewriteRule`.

On the other hand, I can't see why you would need the third line. You're saying that the rewrite should only be applied if `$1$3.php` exists, do you have any other rewrite rules that you are activated if `$1$3.php` file doesn't exist?

Comment: Nope, I guess that's it. I thought the 3rd line would check if `%1%3.php` is a file, but it is true I don't need it (got these lines on another stackoverflow post) as long as it isn't a directory. I don't do anything if the file doesn't exist. Answer accepted :D + you actually tought me stuff -  i guess I would have to play with `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` to use the 3rd line

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't access the Apache docs at the time, that's why it was and still is a guess. If in doubt, docs.